# Unable to compile minecraft mod: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'

Tags: java, maven, gradle, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I was downloading a mod from GitHub (Tetra pack https://github.com/Noobulus/Tetra-Pak/tree/1.18) because the 1.18 version was not yet released as a compiled jar.
I ran the `gradlew build` but It threw this error

> A problem occurred configuring root project 'Tetra-Pak-1.18'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve com.github.gmazzo:gradle-buildconfig-plugin:3.0.1.
> Required by:
> project : > com.github.gmazzo.buildconfig:com.github.gmazzo.buildconfig.gradle.plugin:3.0.1
> Could not resolve com.github.gmazzo:gradle-buildconfig-plugin:3.0.1.
> Could not get resource 'https://dist.creeper.host/Sponge/maven/com/github/gmazzo/gradle-buildconfig-plugin/3.0.1/gradle-buildconfig-plugin-3.0.1.pom'.
> Could not HEAD 'https://dist.creeper.host/Sponge/maven/com/github/gmazzo/gradle-buildconfig-plugin/3.0.1/gradle-buildconfig-plugin-3.0.1.pom'.
> Read timed out

here is the buildscript from build.Gradle.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url = 'https://files.minecraftforge.net/maven' }
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url = 'https://dist.creeper.host/Sponge/maven' }
    maven { url = 'https://repo.spongepowered.org/maven' }
}
dependencies {
    classpath group: 'net.minecraftforge.gradle', name: 'ForgeGradle', version: '5.1.+', changing: true
    classpath group: 'org.spongepowered', name: 'mixingradle', version: '0.7-SNAPSHOT'
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I just removed the dependency that was giving the error from *build.gradle*.